# Does "Positive Christianity" still exist?

Tags: church-history, denomination-survey, germany, christian-identity-movement

Positive Christianity was a movement in Nazi Germany. It advanced interpreting Jesus as an active organiser, preacher and fighter against institutionalised Judaism.

I was wondering if anyone still follows this interpretation? The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_Christianity#Origins_of_the_idea) suggests that it went into decline and suggests that some adherent groups still exist. However, the links don't really lead anywhere.

Comment: Interestingly, positive theology is becoming a buzzword in certain confessional circles to mean, "Affirming things and defining one's theology with positive statement, rather than in the context of things you deny and oppose."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Positive Christianity was actually a movement that existed *prior* to the Nazi's rise to power, but it underwent a mass of redefinitions by the Nazi's. Positive Christianity did not die with Hitler and the Nazi regime in 1945, just as [Nazism](http://www.americannaziparty.com/) didn't die. The original organization may have dissolved with the fall of the Nazi Party, but it has supposedly been adopted by some modern churches with a white supremacist theology who promote a racist interpretation of Christianity. There is a movement in the United States where a number of these churches have united and are known as [*Christian Identity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Identity) Churches. There are less than 50,000 adherents, and the congregations are largely considered extremist hate groups.

---

<sup>[Active Christian Identity Groups](http://www.splcenter.org/get-informed/intelligence-files/ideology/christian-identity/active_hate_groups)</sup>
<sup>[Christian Identity Ministries](http://www.christianidentityministries.com/home.html) (Australia); Tagline:
*"The Anglo-Saxon-Keltic-Germanic-Scandinavian People are Israel"*</sup>
<sup>[Koehne, Samuel. "Nazism And Religion: The Problem Of 'Positive Christianity'." Australian Journal Of Politics & History 60.1 (2014): 28-42.](http://0-onlinelibrary.wiley.com.darius.uleth.ca/doi/10.1111/ajph.12043/pdf) [(link to abstract)](http://0-onlinelibrary.wiley.com.darius.uleth.ca/doi/10.1111/ajph.12043/abstract)</sup>