# Biblical basis or rationale for Christian Identity Movement?

Tags: biblical-basis, israel, racism, christian-identity-movement, british-israelism

After discovering the [Christian Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christian_Identity) movement, and investigating them further to answer another [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/34663/does-positive-christianity-still-exist/34667#34667), I've been pondering how they justify their doctrine.

On the homepage of [Christian Identity Ministries](http://www.christianidentityministries.com/home.html) they quote [Luke 1:68-75](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=luke%201:68-75&version=KJV) and then make this bold statement:

**"The Anglo-Saxon-Keltic-Germanic-Scandinavian People are Israel"**

How does Christian Identity interpret the bible to justify a white supremacist theology?

Comment: I would suppose because somewhere (Revelations? I am not sure) it says that the ten tribes will return from the North?

Answer (score 2):

In Luke here there's a prophecy about the restoration of Israel, pretty similar to many found in the psalms.
Some white supremacists, including these people, believe that the 10 lost tribes of Israel (all except Judah and Benjamin, I think) went to Northern Europe and became the English, and sometimes all the Celtic & Germanic people.
So these verses about Israel being "saved" is evidence to their minds that all the tribes would be preserved, and they see their race as fulfilling that.

Read more about the ten lost tribes if you want to know more.

This is a very biased belief that has almost zero historical evidence, and St. Paul has the view that Christians are the fulfilled children of Abraham (see his *To The Romans*).

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Please see [What this site is about](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/what-christianity-stackexchange-is-and-more-importantly-what-it-isnt/) and [How this site is different](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites/1809#1809) to help you learn how the site works. Also see the [help] and take the [tour] to learn the site functions. I hope to see you post again soon.

Comment: Did you mean to link to a source or were your implying that googling "ten lost tribes" will give me plenty of results. Click [edit] if you meant to put in a link.